# Customize actionbar in actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, styles, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I want to customize my **actionbar** like the **Image shown below**.

[image]

I am using Actionbarsherlock in implementation, as I have shown I will have a total of 5 icons, where 3 of them are centered and the other 2 are at the sides.

There are also separators added,

How do I add a style like this?

Comment: Get an instance of Actionbar class and inflate it with a new layout.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just create a layout. As a separator you can use view with width of 1dp and your icons will be imageviews. Then set this layout to your actionbar.

You can add layout to your actionbar like that:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

View actionBarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.your_layout, null);

actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarView);
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Then if you want to add onClickListener to your ImageView, you can do it like this:

```
ImageView imageViewOption = (ImageView) actionBarView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_option); //it's important to use your actionbar view that you inflated before

imageViewOption.setOnClickListener(...);
```

And if you don't want to have your application icon in actionbar then you can play with setDisplayXXX options. You can find more here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: Hi Michal, thanks for reply, you mean to say create a new linerlayout, and add these images i.e as shown above and set that layout as actionbar. is it possible to make a layout as actionbar??. pls provide me some more details, i am pretty new to this

Comment: I updated my answer. You can just create a layout xml, and then apply it to your ActionBar with code I just added.

Comment: avoid using `actionBar.setCustomView(R.your_layout);` instantly sometimes mess things up!

Comment: What do you mean? Sometimes it's impossible to avoid it if you want to have unusual looking actionbar. I'm not saying that unusual looking actionbar or any other android component is good, but sometimes it's not your choice(i mean if you work for the company with a "designer":p ) so there is an API for that.